# How to prevent sensitive data from being logged by SyncInvoker.post?

Tags: java, logging, javax.ws.rs, javax

I'm sending a request with a following code:

```
final WebTarget target = client.target(url);
CustomResponse response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
                          .post(Entity.xml(password), CustomResponse.class);
```

Authentication is designed to accept username as a part of `url` while password is sent in request body.

The issue is that password is shown in logs which are generated by class `ClientRequest#writeEntity()` inside `javax.ws.rs` library.

So, my question is how force that library not to store password in logs without turning logging off?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you at least encrypt a bit the passord ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom [java.util.logging.Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) and install it on the [java.util.logging.Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setFilter-java.util.logging.Filter-) that is generating the [log record](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html).  You can either just omit that log entry by returning `false` or simply re-write the parameter or message of the log record so that it doesn't contain the password.

```
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;


public class PasswordFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        if (isPasswordCallSite(record)) {
           //return false; // omit log entry.
           //Or hide password.
           Object[] params = record.getParameters();
           if (params != null && params.length != 0) {
               params = params.clone();
               String data = String.valueOf(params[0]);

                //Write code to find and replace password.
               params[0] = data;
               record.setParameters(params);
           }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean isPasswordCallSite(LogRecord r) {
        return "foo.bar.ClientRequest".equals(r.getSourceClassName())
                && "writeEntity".equals(r.getSourceMethodName());
    }
}
```